# Почему не работает условие?

Tags: javascript, jquery, условия

Всем привет. Почему не работает условие?

```
if ($('.wp-post-image').height() + $('.product-section h3').height() != 346px)        {
    console.log("не стандарт");
}
```

Пишет: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript не понимает, что значит `360px`. Распарсится так:

```
360 px
```

То есть, `360` - число, и `px` - название переменной. Нельзя поставить название переменной после число без оператора. Поэтому выводит "Unexpected identifier".

Надо без `px`:

```
if ($('.wp-post-image').height() + $('.product-section h3').height() !== 346) {
    console.log("не стандарт");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Присоединяюсь в первому ответу, но все же рекомендую условие оформить правильно:

```
if( ($('.wp-post-image').height() + $('.product-section h3').height()) != 346 ){
    console.log("не стандарт");
}
```

*...обернуть скобками...*

Comment: а почему в вашем случае неравенство `borodatych` - это в данном случае принципиально?

Comment: В данном случая не принципиально, я просто корректировал Ваш код. Можно использовать и `!==`(сравнит и значение и тип), и `!=`(сравнит только значение).